# Is there a way to tell if a JFrame is "Maximised" (MS Windows)

Tags: java, windows, swing, jframe, window-managers

I've been Java applications on OS X, and haven't had the opportunity to fully test in different places.

There are 2 different `JFrame`s. The second is loaded exactly in place of the first one, and as such needs to have its size and location set to the same as the first.

This works fine, but I noticed a lot of Windows users seem to maximise the first window. When the second JFrame loads, it has the same size, but is not "maximised".

Maximised windows in the MS Windows world have a slightly different state and are treated differently by the OS.

How can I tell if a JFrame is Maximised, and how can I maximise one myself?

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507772/maximizing-a-jframe-on-action

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
frame.setExtendedState( f.getExtendedState()|JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
```

Comment: and `frame.getExtendedState()` for the first question